# Why are the new Star Wars busts 18+?

Tags: star-wars

My new Boba Fett set 75277 arrived this morning, and the first thing that struck me was the 18+ classification. Am I right in thinking this is purely there because the set is intended for a more mature builder?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE. I think you edited away the end of your last sentence :)

Comment: No, mindstormsboi did but the edit is pending approval. No idea why mindstormsboi did that... I rejected the edit, and now I've lost my original text and the history. Sigh.

Comment: This is probably a smartphone issue. Someone calls while you are bidding on Ebay and editing text at the same time.

Comment: Who knows. Anyway, I've sort of restored it.

Answer (score 3):

[Product description](https://brickset.com/sets/75277-1/Boba-Fett) (cannot embed URL for description, so you have to click on "DESCRIPTION" tab) explains why adults are a target audience. (emphasis is mine)

> It’s a super LEGO Star Wars™ gift idea for adult fans and **offers a
>   testing challenge for experienced LEGO builders**, with the familiar
>   shape and authentic details of the helmet beautifully recreated using
>   LEGO bricks.
>
> Pay homage to one of the most fearsome bounty hunters in the Star
>   Wars™ universe and **challenge your LEGO® building skills** to construct
>   this awesome Boba Fett Helmet (75277) memorabilia model for display.
>
> The authentic details of the Boba Fett Helmet are beautifully
>   reproduced with LEGO® bricks. Displayed on its base with nameplate,
>   this model will spark memories of thrilling Star Wars™ scenes.
>
> This Boba Fett Helmet is part of a range of collectible LEGO® Star
>   Wars™ **build-and-display models** – also watch out for the Stormtrooper
>   Helmet (75276).
>
> The best birthday gift, Christmas present or special surprise **for Star
>   Wars™ fans aged 18+ and any experienced LEGO® builder**, this 625-piece
>   Star Wars Boba Fett Helmet offers a challenging construction project.
>
> This LEGO® Star Wars™ Boba Fett Helmet measures 8.5” (21cm) high, 4.5”
>   (11cm) wide and 4.5” (11cm) deep – it doesn’t take up lot of space,
>   but its striking details are sure to delight any Star Wars fan.
>
> This cool, battery-free construction **set for creative adults offers a
>   stress-relieving, relaxing build**. So, take time out, find your
>   building Zen and construct a fantastic Star Wars™ character
>   build-and-display model!
>
> **Thinking of buying this Boba Fett memorabilia for a Star Wars™ fan new
>   to LEGO® sets? No worries. It comes with clear, step-by-step
>   instructions so they can take on this complex building challenge with
>   confidence.**
>
> LEGO® Star Wars™ construction sets are great for kids and adult fans
>   to build and display the models, recreate classic Star Wars movie
>   scenes and create their own exciting stories. There’s something for
>   everyone!
>
> No need to use the Force to connect or pull apart LEGO® bricks! They
>   meet the highest industry standards to ensure consistency and a
>   perfect, easy connection.
>
> LEGO® bricks and pieces are dropped, heated, crushed, twisted and
>   analyzed to ensure that this LEGO Star Wars™ set meets the highest
>   safety standards on Earth (and in galaxies far, far away!).

Basically a little more challenging build and not intended for play are the main reasons, I suppose.

Although I'm not sure why they both mention "+18", "adults" as well kids in the same description, like here:

> LEGO® Star Wars™ construction sets are great for kids and adult fans
>   to build and display the models, recreate classic Star Wars movie
>   scenes and create their own exciting stories. There’s something for
>   everyone!

**EDIT**. LEGO has released new 10273 Haunted House set with a [press release](https://www.lego.com/en-us/aboutus/news/2020/may/lego-haunted-house-2020) explaining why some new sets have "18+" marking.

> Addressing the new packaging, Senior Marketing Manager Anders Hellegaard Iversen said: “So many of our older builders love the Creator Expert products, as they allow them to show off their passion for the bricks. Whether it’s their favourite film moments, sport icons, travel destinations, buildings, fairgrounds or vehicles, LEGO sets help to bring these to life in brick form. That’s also why we have decided to stop using the Creator Expert branding and, instead, use the new adult-focused packaging design to make it clearer which hobbies or brand products they can relate to. We hope this will make it easier for fans to track down models they would be proud to display once completed. Of course, our product range will continue to include the same advanced-build, collectible products that guarantee hours of building enjoyment for fans.”

Comment: Thanks Alex. Interestingly, my 7 year old asked if he could help build it. I said he's not over 18, so he's not allowed to. He came back with "Oh, so I can't build any more 12+ sets yet then?". The noticeable difference with this set over a 12+ set or something like 42110 11+ Technics set is that there are less granular steps. What I mean by that is, you get a step with a list of say 12 bricks, and 1 image to work out where they all go. In a 12+ set the steps would be more granular, with more guidance on where to place the bricks. Total build time on 75277 was just under an hour.

Comment: It is sort of similar with those sets with age recommendation set up to 99 (8455 set as an example). Should you stop building at the age of 99? Probably not, if you still can. And I loved building sets with recommended age above mine when I was a kid. Such sets were somewhat more complex but then much more rewarding to build.

Comment: The press release link seems to just take me to a generic Lego landing page.

Comment: @spikey_richie That's because you haven't opened lego.com page before/recently. I've checked in my main browser - all opens fine; and with incognito mode it opens the page you've mentioned, however choosing "Explore" option will let you see the press release.

Comment: I was on there yesterday browsing Harry Potter Lego... But curiously, when I go back in now it does show the article. Curious.